# Python Bottle - Get variable from template

Tags: python, templates, bottle

I have template-file (.tpl) which has some additional python code in it, that stores data into a variable.
How can I access this variable when I send/handle a POST request from that template?

Can anyone give me a quick example?

In .tpl:

```
...
%dummy="TEST"
...
```

In main.py:

```
...
@post('/template/')
def method():
    ????
...
```

Edit: After a little brainstorming im not sure if thats even possible. The ,tpl is more or less a HTML page, which, as far as I know, cannot transfer stuff like variables,structures like lists etc.
Can anyone please confirm?

Comment: More information would help.  What's in your template?  An html form?  And what do you want to happen when the user hits "submit?"

Comment: Probably you should set this var in your route handler, not in template. Any reason to not do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable in the url

```
<form action="/template/?variable={{dummy}}>
```

and then in the handler:

```
dammy = request.query.variable
```

See the related [docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#query-variables)